# Which deities in the Forgotten Realms were once mortal?

Tags: forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

My research indicates that the gods who were once mortals include the following:

- **Azuth** was once the mortal champion of Mystra and ascended to godhood after imprisoning Savras.
- **Bane**, **Bhaal**, and **Myrkul** (also known as the Dead Three) became gods when Jergal gave up his powers.
- **Cyric** once was a thief, but ascended to godhood during the Time of Troubles by slaying Bhaal.
- **Finder Wyvernspur** was once an accomplished bard and (after some trouble) killed Moander and claimed his divine spark.
- **Gwaeron Windstrom** was made a demigod by Mielikki after he killed an avatar and several manifestations of Malar.
- **Kelemvor** was once a human fighter named Kelemvor Lyonsbane. He became a god after defeating Cyric.
- When the previous **Mystra** was destroyed by Helm, Ao replaced her with Midnight, a powerful wizard.
- **Savras** once was a powerful mage who somehow became a god.
- **Torm** was once a mortal hero and became a demigod during the time when Netheril fell.
- **Valkur** may have once been mortal.

Are there others? What's the full list of Forgotten Realms deities that were once mortal?

Also, all the deities I've found were humans before their ascensions. Have any nonhumans become deities?

Comment: I recommend asking just the question as per the title then self-answering with your list—you should get credit for both. Also, consider saving the secondary question — *Why don't nonhumans ascend to godhood?* — for a separate question after this one's received some attention.

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan. I already know some of the deities who were once mortal. So I didn't want to waste everybody's time. So I included them in my question. Yes, maybe I should ask the second question after this question gave me the answers I nedd.

Comment: O, I totally get wanting to be cool about it, but as one who frequently answers list questions,  answers that stand on their own usually end up being *better answers* — more readable, complete, and attractive — than answers that must reference the question to note exclusions.  I mean, every answer will already feel obligated to at least mention the gods the question excludes anyway, so it's *already* like a partial answer. Like I said, it was merely a recommendation; ultimately, it remains your question.

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan. Thanks for your comment. This is only my sixth question I've asked here and I am still not sure how to do it in an optimal way. For now, I will leave this question as it is, but depending on the answers I get, I will change the question or take them into consideration for future questions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## After flipping through all of the relevant rulebooks from each edition here is my list (including non-humans):

(as of 3-23-2018) *those in italics are only possibly originally mortal (based on stories or legends)*

### Faerûnian Pantheon:

1. **Azuth:** ascended by his own power with the help of Mystra (PnP 47)
2. **Bane:** ascended with the Dead Three through the slaying of one of the Seven Lost Gods (F&A 37)
3. **Bhaal:** see Bane (one of the Dead Three), his second incarnation is the divine form of the victor of the duel between Abdel Adrian and Viekang (F&A 37; SCAG 17)
4. **Cyric:** ascended by inheriting Bhaal's powers having slain him (PoL)
5. **Finder:** ascended from the divine spark of the late Moander
6. **Gargauth** ascended by absorbing the powers of many demons including, at least, Astaroth (PnP 22)
7. **Gwaeron Windstrom:** ascended as reward from Mielikki for killing avatars and manifestations of Malar (FnP 96)
8. **Kelemvor:** ascended by winning favor with all the dead by defeating Cyric
9. **Mask:** reborn from Riven who gathered more and more of Mask's dormant power until the boy became the new incarnation (Shadowrealm)
10. **Mystra** ascended after the fall of Netheril by her own power (NEoM 19)
11. **Midnight** ascended as the new Mystra, selected by Ao to end the Time of Troubles (FRCP 265)
12. **Red Knight:** ascended with the help of Tempus (FnP 104)
13. **Savras:** no details on ascension (MoF 6)
14. **Siamorphe:** divinity is passed down through mortal lineage (PnP 58-60)
15. **Torm** no details on ascension (FnP 74)
16. **Uthgar** ascended as a reward from Tempus for his noble fight with the Pale Giants (FRCS 255)
17. **Velsharoon** ascended with the help of Talos (GHoR 149)
18. **Waukeen** became mortal briefly in an attempt to be free of Ao's bond during the Time of Troubles (FDnD 4)
19. ***Valkur:*** ascended by winning a challenge against Umberlee (FnP 110)

### Kara-Turan Pantheon

1. **Chan Cheng:** ascended due to a blessing for his great leadership as a ruler (GHoR 33)

### Zakharan Pantheon

1. ***Jarmik:*** may have been mortal at one time, ascending where the Mosque of the Thirsty Jann is now (CoD 33-34)

### Drow Pantheon

1. **Kiaransalee:** no details on ascension (FnP 113)

### Dwarven Pantheon

1. ***Deep Duerra:*** no details on ascension

### Yuir Elvish Pantheon

1. **Elikarashae:** no details on ascension (SCG 53)

### Others

1. ***Baphomet:*** while a demon lord, rather than a deity, he may have uniquely started as a mortal creature, banished to the Abyss by the gods
2. **Kuraulyek:** ascended with the help of Asgorath (GHoR 9)
3. **Kurtulmak:** ascended with the help of Asgorath (GHoR 9)

### Dead Deities

1. **Myrkul:** see Bane (one of the Dead Three), currently in an artifact (Waterdeep)
2. **Tchazzar:** ascended through part of Tiamat's divinity when Tiamat was slain by Gilgeam, may or not be divine still (DoF 37-39)
3. **Zinzerena:** ascended in a different crystal sphere before arriving in the Forgotten Realms, sponsored by a deity named Keptolo (VotD)

***Rivalen Tanthul***, **Erevis Cale**, **Kesson Rel**, and **Mephistopheles** each acquired divinity briefly until Mask was fully reincarnated in Drasek Riven (Shadowrealm)

---

Sources used:

- City of Delights (CoD)
- Dragons of Faerûn (DoF)
- Faiths & Avatars (F&A)
- Faiths and Pantheons (FnP)
- For Duty and Deity (FDnD)
- Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting 3e (FRCP)
- Magic of Faerûn (MoF)
- Netheril: Empire of Magic (NEoM)
- Prince of Lies (PoL)
- Powers and Pantheons (PnP)
- Shadowrealm
- Spellbound (SCG)
- Swords Coast Adventurer's Guide (SCAG)
- "The Vault of the Drow." Dragon #298. (VotD)
- The Grand History of the Realms (GHoR)
- Waterdeep

Comment: Would Mystra (#10) count though? You're already mentioning Midnight (#11), so...

Comment: @Roflo Both Mystra became deities separately as different mortals so I put the both.

Comment: Wait, so the "Netheril-Mystra" was mortal too? And ascended by her own non-godly power? I thought Karsus was the only one who had done that. But I guess I might have missed that bit.

Comment: @Roflo yeah she saved her people by catchimg three collapsing floating city as a barely trained peasant girl and was like yo I'm awesome. All arcanists listen to me now.

Comment: While the exact details are not given, some background about Kiaransalee's ascension is given in 2e *Demihuman Deities*.

Comment: @ZwiQ I don't think I have that book. You are welcome to edit it in.

Answer (score 6):

1. Drasek Riven (human)- became the second Mask, Lord of Shadows
2. Rivalen Tanthul (human) - became a demigod by absorbing a shard of
   Mask's divinity after killing Kesson Rel
3. Erevis Cale (human) - as per Rivalen
4. Kesson Rel (human) - demigod from Mask's divine essence
5. Velsharoon (lich wizard) - managed to ascend to exarch godhood with
   the sponsorship of the deity Talos
6. The Red Knight (human) - elevated to exarch divinity by Tempus to balance Garagos' destructive aims

Answer (score 4):

Deep Duerra (Dark Dwarf - now dead) - Female Duergar promoted to Demigod by Laduguer for successfully "stealing" psionics from the Illithids

Comment: I couldn't find a source for Laduguer's involvement in her ascension.

Answer (score 0):

Technically both Cyric and Midnight were appointed (given the portfolios of?) by Ao because the respective deities were slain. They didn't ascend simply by killing the gods. Ao had to say OK.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack! Have you taken the [tour]? There is some good information here, but could you perhaps elaborate a little and offer some citations? Well supported answers fare much better in the Q&A format of the site.